# How to bulk read and write data from multidimensional arrays picking only the columns?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a bit of code that gets each column separately from a multidimensional array and paste in to a worksheet column. Wehn i run it line by line, i see that it copies the values into ResultArr correctly, but when it writes values to worksheet it paste the first value from that array into the whole column. I'm completely stuck on how to bulk write the data, is there a fix / better way to do this? The Flag is the number of rows, in double.

```
Sub MainSub()

Dim dValueData As Variant
Dim ResultArr() As Variant

'Some code here to get value for dValueData array which has 7000 rows and 6 
columns, which also involves another sub. I can see that this array has correct values and length.

' Bulk writes data into Daily Views sheet to speed up code
Call GetColumn(0)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Call GetColumn(1)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M2:M" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Call GetColumn(2)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Call GetColumn(3)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:G" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Call GetColumn(4)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2:I" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Call GetColumn(5)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F2:F" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H2:H" & Flag).Value = ResultArr
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J2:J" & Flag).Value = ResultArr

End Sub

Sub GetColumn(ColumnNumber As Long)

Dim RowNdx As Long
' Ensure Arr is an array.
If IsArray(dValueData) = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' Ensure ColumnNumber is less than or equal to the number of columns.
If UBound(dValueData, 2) < ColumnNumber Then
     Exit Sub
End If
If LBound(dValueData, 2) > ColumnNumber Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ReDim ResultArr(LBound(dValueData, 1) To UBound(dValueData, 1), 1)
For RowNdx = LBound(ResultArr) To UBound(ResultArr)
    ResultArr(RowNdx, 1) = dValueData(RowNdx, ColumnNumber)
Next RowNdx

End Sub
```

Comment: Transpose and Application.Index to slice a column out of the array and write to sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 1-based arrays (as you have if built from a Range) then you can simply go:

```
Call GetColumn(2)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E" & Flag).Value = Application.Transpose(ResultArr)
```

and

```
Sub GetColumn(ColumnNumber As Long)
    ' Ensure Arr is an array.
    If IsArray(dValueData) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Ensure ColumnNumber is less than or equal to the number of columns.
    If UBound(dValueData, 2) < ColumnNumber Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    If LBound(dValueData, 2) > ColumnNumber Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ResultArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(dValueData, 0, ColumnNumber))
End Sub
```

Comment: The transpose solved my problem! But i only did it at the worksheet write part, and left the GetColumn sub alone because that would be transposing it twice?

Comment: if you don't transpose it in GetColumn() also, then you write the same value in all the cells along the worksheet column